# Can root element have text in it?

Tags: xml, dtd

Can root element have text in it?

For example if the DTD is:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” standalone=”yes” ?>
<!DOCTYPE items [
 <!ELEMENT items (item*) >
 <!ELEMENT item (article,country,price)+ >
]>
```

can the XML document be `<items>hello</items>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Text is `#PCDATA`, the DTD does not say you can include `#PCDATA` there, so *no*.

Comment: So just to make it clear, <!ELEMENT items (#PCDATA)> should have been added, right?

Comment: Then you would have two definitions of `<items>`. You need to edit the existing definition.

Comment: So it would've been <!ELEMENT items (#PCDATA) (item*) > ?

Comment: @user11638558 - it would be `<!ELEMENT items (#PCDATA|item)*>`